# Multiple QGIS labels depending on field

Tags: qgis, labeling

I want to make an label expression to label with "pHole_ID" if the "Status" is 'Planned' and label with "ActualHole_ID" if the "Status" is 'Completed'.

I have tried:

```
case 
  when "Status" like 'Planned' then "pHole_ID" 
  else "Status" like 'Completed' then "ActualHole_ID" 
end
```

but to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use a single expression rather than (the perfectly fine) rule based solution from @Maximilien jaffrès you should use two WHEN for your expression so :

```
CASE
  WHEN "Status" like 'Planned' THEN "pHole_ID"
  WHEN "Status" like 'Completed' THEN "ActualHole_ID"
  ELSE 'not in rule'  (use the ELSE only if you want a label when the rules return noting, if not remove the whole line)
END
```

Also you use the like operator but dont use any wildcard so you should use something like this `WHEN "Status" like '%Planned%'` if you want all entry of "Status" that contain the string 'Planned' (or simply use `WHEN "Status" = 'Planned'` to get entry where "Status" contains exactly the string 'Planned')

Answer (score 4):

You should use labelling with rules and lay down your rules in unique row

for exemple i made this rule :

if "validity" = True i use column "z_crest1"

if "validity" = False i use column "z_crest2"

[image]

In your case it should be something along the line of

if "Status"= 'Planned' use "pHole_ID"

if "Status" = 'Completed' use "ActualHole_ID"

Note that you can also use else in theses expressions and declare as many rules as you need.